# How to draw a frame by frame Animation from frame x to frame y

Tags: android, animation

I want to know if there is any solution available in Android that will allow me to define an Animation by entering a set of frames to it (images), And then allow me to play from frame number x to y.

I'm currently using **AnimationDrawable** for frame by frame animations and it seems to lack that functionality.

Is there maybe a different Class that could help me here?

Thanks a lot!

Ita

Answer (score 1):

You can add frames x through y to a new AnimationDrawable using [addFrame(Drawable frame, int duration)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html#addFrame%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20int%29). Since you mentioned images, you should use a BitmapDrawable to load your images and then pass it to the AnimationDrawable along with the duration.